Tail behaviour of an inverse Fourier transform of complex function with poles
The generalized chi-square random variable has a complicated-looking characteristic function (a complex function), with several poles of different orders:
$$\displaystyle \phi(t) = \frac{\exp\left[it \left( m + \sum_j \frac{w_j \lambda_j}{1-2i w_j t} \right)-\frac{s^2 t^2}{2}\right]}{\prod_j \left(1-2i w_j t \right)^{k_j/2}}.$$
$k_j, \lambda_j$ are positive constants, $w_j,s,m$ are positive or negative constants.
The PDF of the variable is its inverse Fourier transform: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t)\; e^{-itx}\;dt$.
I am interested in how $f(x)$, this inverse Fourier transform of a complex function, behaves asymptotically in its tails, i.e. as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$. It has been observed that it might decay like $\lvert x \rvert^a e^{-b\lvert x \rvert}$ there. I want to find $a$ and $b$ from $\phi$.
Some tinkering with numerics and chatGPT indicates the following:

chatGPT says that the tail behaviour of $f(x)$ arises from the poles of $\phi$, and their orders, and should follow $\lvert x \rvert^a e^{-b\lvert x \rvert}$, where the exponent $b$ should be inversely proportional to the largest positive/negative $w_j$, and the factor $a$ should depend on the order $k_j$ of the pole corresponding to that $w_j$.
Numerically, I also see that the exponent $b$ for the upper/lower tail of $f(x)$ only depends inversely on the largest positive/negative $w_j$, but also depends on the corresponding $\lambda_j$. It does not depend on the other $w_j$'s, or any $k_j$'s, or $s$ or $m$.

Specifically, I would like to know the following:

An explanation of why and how the tail behaviour of $f(x)$ arises from the poles and orders of its Fourier conjugate $\phi$.
How is the dependence on $\lambda_j$ arising, that was not indicated by chatGPT?
What are the tail decay parameters $a$ and $b$ in terms of the parameters in $\phi$?


Don't use chatGPT for math. It's like trying to solve a math problem by reading paper mache made out of mathematical textbooks. We do not engage in ellucidating the random output of synthetic text extruders in this site.
